# Jquery when i click on img it behaves like link (triggering link)

Tags: jquery, click, eventtrigger

i have a problem, I got some li, inside them i have a link and an image. What i want is when someone clicks on the image it triggers the link. I cant put the image in a link, don't ask why :)... So basically it looks something like this

```
<li><a href="somelink">sometext</a><img src=""/></li>
<li><a href="somelink">sometext</a><img src=""/></li>
...
```

And i was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$(img).click(function(){
  var link = $(this).prev;
  $(link).trigger('click');
})
```

I know this is not correct, but i think you got the picture, thanks for your help.

Comment: Why can't you put the image in the link?

Comment: Quote from the OP : ". I cant put the image in a link, don't ask why :)."

Comment: Always challenge assumptions - if nothing else share the motives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('img').live('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('a').click();
});
```

Comment: Wouw i have to tell you this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much dude... you just saved my day... take care

Answer (score 4):

Don't use jQuery, but simply move the closing `</a>` tag at the right side of the `<img>` tag:

```
<li><a href="somelink">sometext<img src=""/></a></li>
<li><a href="somelink">sometext<img src=""/></a></li>
```

If you don't want to change the HTML, use:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    location.href = $(this).prev().attr("href");
});
```

---

### Code review

- `$(img)` - `img` is not defined. Did you mean: `$('img')`? (added quotes, using selector `img`)
- `var link = $(this).prev;` - `prev` is nto a property, but a method. It has to be invoked: `var link = $(this).prev()`
- `$(link).trigger('click')`. Since `link` is a jQuery object already, it's unnecessary to wrap the object in another jQuery object. Use: `link.trigger('click');`
- Flawed logic: `.trigger('click')` will not cause the page to be followed, because it doesn't trigger the default browser behaviour (following the link), but invokes the `click` event of the element. Which is not defined.

Comment: yes, ok your right, but how can i simulate the click on the link, by clicking on the image ?

Comment: @Mr.Sam It's the second code block at my answer. The default behavior of clicking a link is changing the location, which is achieved using (e.g.) `location.href = "http://newurl";`

Comment: thanks but i was looking for something that not just redirects the page but triggers the link... but thanks anyway

Comment: @Mr.Sam Triggering the link == redirecting the page. Even if the link contains a bookmarket (`javscript:..`) or just a hash (`#notleaving`), the page will not redirect, and the link will be followed, as if you are following a link.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that looks like it oughta work. Just note that prev is a function.

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
window.location = link.attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with something like

```
$(img).click(function()
{   
      var link = $(this).prev();   
      window.location.href = link.attr('href'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a css class for both the anchor link and the image and use a classname selector to hook the click event

$(".myclass").click(function(){
//Do Stuff
})

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific because i think your on to something... i mean i like this alternative