# Jquery use a class to bind link and image

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, jquery

Hy, i this problem, have some li's and in theme a link and an image:

```
<li><a  href"somelink"></a><img src-""/></li> 
<li><a  href"somelink"></a><img src-""/></li> 
...
```

I want to bind the img with the link, i mean when someone clicks on the image the link gets click on or something like this... but i dont want to use window.location.href.... i'm intrested if i could hook theme together using the same class... is this possible ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you could just put the image inside the link?

Comment: Sam, use appropriate tags. What does "hook" or "bin" have to do with the question? Also, you've got several spelling mistakes in your code.

Comment: i cant, i have a lot of stuff going on with the images, animations and so on... anyway i just cant... im interested in something else...but thanks

Comment: @Mr.Sam - So you want a click on the image to follow the link, but you don't want to use `window.location`?

Comment: Be more specific in your question but the first bad thing I see is that you must wrap the image with the a tag. <li><a href"somelink"><img src=""/></a></li>

Comment: @RobW yes i know sorry for the spelling mistakes but the example code is just to give you an visual image how my code looks like... its not like this of course... and about the "hook" and "bin" well sorry im just new to jquery and i tried to find some reference and i thought this is hase something to do with binding or hooking :) things togather

Comment: Don't replicate questions. Just edit your previous one if you feel that one minor detail has been forgotten: [Jquery when i click on img it behaves like link (triggering link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918719/jquery-when-i-click-on-img-it-behaves-like-link-triggering-link).

Comment: Mr. Sam: why can't you put the `img` inside the `a`? If you use html properly it makes things much, ***much*** easier. Also, if you can use jQuery/JavaScript then use *that* to move the `img` elements into the adjacent `a`.

Comment: ok listen, maybe you need to see this to understand... so here is the page http://kavezo.biz i have the fruits on the right... they are images and the links next the them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page you posted:

```
$('#header_menu li a + img').click(
    function(){
        document.location = $(this).prev('a').attr('href');
        /* or:
        $(this).prev('a').click();
        */
    });
```

Comment: Soory scratch that to it does work ... thank you verry verry much

Answer (score 3):

Be more specific but if you want to create a link out of an image you must wrap it with the a tag.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://foo.com"></a><img src="" class="image-element" /></li>
  <li><a href="http://foo.com"></a><img src="" class="image-element" /></li>
</ul>

// Using Live w/ Click Event
$('.image-element').live('click', function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).prev().attr("href");
});

// Click Event
$('.image-element').click(function(){  
    window.location.href = $(this).prev().attr("href");
});
```

Here's the window.location doc.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: this is not what i'm looking for, thanks but i want to use a class on my image tag and the link tag and somehow bind them togather so when i write my code in jquery i use the class... does this make and sens to you ?

Comment: No. You want to click on the image and *then what should happen*? `document.location` will be used if you want to follow the link (regardless of using it with JavaScript, the default behaviour is to follow the link, which changes the `document.location`). Outline, in your question, step-by-step what you want to happen.

Comment: @DavidThomas well yes i think your right but ok, listen i tried a lot of things but maybe because my link's href is only "/something" nothing seems to work, so when someone clicks on the image the link next to it gets "clicked on"

Comment: I have no idea what doesn't work; but I also have no idea what you expect it to do, and what's going wrong: ***what do you want to happen***?

Comment: well ok scratch everything and look at this code:  `$('img').click(function(){
window.location = $(this).prev().attr("href"); });` So this should work but it doesnt

Comment: Oh crap! you need to use window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work?

```
$('img.clicky').bind('click', function() {
    var h = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().attr('href', h).click();
});
```

It required you to have, as mentioned, `<img>` inside the `<a>`-tag instead:

`<a href=""><img class="clicky" src="" /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="linkify">
    <li><a href="somelink"></a><img src="" /></li> 
    <li><a href="somelink"></a><img src="" /></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.linkify img').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('a:eq(0)').click();
    });
});
</script>
```